# Understanding Identity functor

Tags: haskell, functor

I am working my way through this [tutorial](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/adjunctions.html). As documented in the tutorial, I copied some code as below, to represent `functor composition` and `identity functor`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Test where

newtype FComp f g a = C { unC :: f (g a) }

instance (Show (f (g a))) => Show (FComp f g a) where
  show (C x) = "FComp " ++ show x

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (FComp f g) where
  fmap h (C x) = C (fmap (fmap h) x)

newtype Id a = Identity { unId :: a } deriving Show

instance Functor Id where
    fmap f x = Identity (f (unId x))
```

Now, this is what the tutorial states about `identity functor`:

```
Composition with the identity functor in the same category is as expected.
F∘IdB = F  
IdA∘F = F
```

What I am stuck at is trying to think of it in terms of functor composition as represented by `FComp` in the code above. An example below:

```
$ let a = C (Identity (Just (5::Int)))
$ :t a
a :: FComp Id Maybe Int
$ let b = C (Just (Identity (5::Int)))
$ :t b
b :: FComp Maybe Id Int
```

I can't think of a way to assert that types of `a` and `b` as represented in example above are identical. I will appreciate pointers on how to think of `identity functor` in terms of `functor composition`.

Comment: Your functors are better described as isomorphic, rather than identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like many equations in Haskell-applied category theory, *F* ∘ Id<sub>*B*</sub> ≡ Id<sub>*A*</sub> ∘ *F* ≡ *F* should really just be read as *equivalences*. `FComp Id Maybe Int` is very much not the same thing as `FComp Maybe Id Int` to the type checker; however you can easily write

```
idFunctorIso :: Functor f => FComp f Id a -> f a
idFunctorIso (C fIdca) = fmap unId fIdca

idFunctorIso' :: Functor f => f a -> FComp f Id a
idFunctorIso' fa = C $ fmap Identity fIdc
```

which implies that both types contain the same information<sup>1</sup>. That's what we mean by saying they're isomorphic.

---

<sup>1</sup>No information is lost in either direction, since `idFunctorIso' . idFunctorIso ≡ id` (as follows from the functor law `fmap id ≡ id`, together with the fact that `unC` and `unId` are simple inverses of the newtype constructors).

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what it means to be able to write these functions. Especially that `idFunctorIso . idFunctorIso'` is equivalent to `id` (which is easier to show using point-free implementations).

Comment: @Rhymoid: right. ...Why don't you write that yourself though? You needn't have deleted your answer, even if it heavily overlaps with mine... extra elaboration and more than one point of view can never harm.

Comment: The mental postfixing of "up to isomorphism" is usually appropriate for category theory in Haskell.